# Sonata Admin+ACL-Different dashboard for different roles

Tags: fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata

Well I am trying to achieve this using sonata admin bundle+ fosuser+ ACL

Three level of users –-normal user----staff----super admin
When each user logs in each user is redirected to admin dashboard but shown only some admin items (listing) and user other than super admin allowed to edit only own items

I implemented everything as on listed here
http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/security.html

I ran all acl command(inits and so on) everything is working fine

But sonata admin roles are so confusing.
Rather than editing roles of every single user I am assigning user to groups (creating 3 groups normal,staff and super admin) and assigning roles to it(group).

But I am really confused what roles should be assigned to staff and normal user.
If I assigned ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN role the user is able to do everything.

If I assign only ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN to group the dashboard is empty without any items.

So how can I achieve what I want?
Thanks.

current roles here
http://i59.tinypic.com/iwlkjt.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You should set permissions for each admin separately. On your picture I cannot see admin bundles to manage permissions except relation bundle (GalleryHasMedia) wich is shown when you operate on many-to-many relation. You only have permissions to `ROLE_SONATA_MEDIA_ADMIN_GALLERY_HAS_MEDIA` set for STAFF. I can imagine that you don't have blocks for this relation on the dashboard or on your left sidebar menu.

First of all you should run this command every time you add any Admin (in case you didn't):

```
app/console sonata:admin:setup-acl
```

Assuming that you have SonataMediaBundle you should have among others following ROLEs:

```
ROLE_SONATA_MEDIA_ADMIN_GALLERY_GUEST
ROLE_SONATA_MEDIA_ADMIN_GALLERY_STAFF
ROLE_SONATA_MEDIA_ADMIN_GALLERY_EDITOR
ROLE_SONATA_MEDIA_ADMIN_GALLERY_ADMIN
```

Assuming that you configured your permissions as following:

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl
        # acl security information
        information:
            GUEST:    [VIEW, LIST]
            STAFF:    [EDIT, LIST, CREATE]
            EDITOR:   [OPERATOR, EXPORT]
            ADMIN:    [MASTER]

        admin_permissions: [CREATE, LIST, DELETE, UNDELETE, EXPORT, OPERATOR, MASTER]
```

So if you want user X:

- to see Gallery list  then you should give him GUEST permissions on given  on given Admin
- to see Gallery list, edit own items and create new ones then you should give him STAFF permissions on given Admin
- to see Gallery list, edit each items and create new ones then you should give him OPERATOR permissions on given Admin
- to do everything else (i.e delete, change permissions) set MASTER pemissions on given Admin

Try also to extend your ROLE_ADMIN hierarchy (at app/config/security.yml):

```
ROLE_ADMIN:             [ROLE_STAFF, ROLE_SONATA_EDITOR, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
```

Regards.

Comment: I have tried to summarize my problem in the picture in the link.I have created a user group "Agent" and assigned user to it called "agent1". I want user assigned to that group able to add,edit,delete their own items with a dashboard but currently the dashboard appear empty.Problem in picture here:
[link](http://s15.postimg.org/fs18knzuz/problem.jpg)

Comment: Add ROLE_ADMIN to Agent group.

Comment: I mean ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN but it's included in ROLE_ADMIN. See in SonataAdminbundle:standard_layout.html.twig

Comment: But sorry I didn't get it.If you see in image ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN is checked for agent group(and also all staff roles).I am attaching another image which shows that is active for agent group(user agent1 is in agent user group).I am able to login to dashboard but it is empty for agent1 as shown in image in comment above.
[link](http://s3.postimg.org/fg9l9cjoz/agent.jpg)

Comment: So it should work. Unless you didn't set sonata:admin:setup-acl and to update object created outside the Admin: sonata:admin:generate-object-acl.

Comment: Thanks for all help.I did it ran php app/console sonata:admin:setup-acl  and php app/console sonata:admin:generate-object-acl.I tried doing it again but still not working. In fact i found that  logging as agent1 if i manually access url app_dev.php/admin/pro/propertycategory/create or edit it is working but app_dev.php/admin/pro/propertycategory/list is not working and giving 403 error message i.e C U D is working but R(list) is not working and dashboard is empty.Still not solved.

Comment: Please run `app/console sonata:admin:setup-acl --help` and `app/console sonata:admin:generate-object-acl --help` you will see that those methods come up with --env option wich in default is set to "dev".

Comment: Yes I am developing all things in dev environment[mode]. I am really not sure what to do now.